# Widehat with right arrow

Tags: math-mode

I am searching for a wide hat with a right arrow. So far I've found only the regular wide hat (`\widehat`, shown at the left of the image), or a curved right arrow (`\curvearrowright`).

[image: Wide had and wide hat with arrow]

Is there a way to get something like what I have badly drawn at the right of the image?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I have included your image. Soon, you will have enough reputation to do it yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I provide two TikZ solutions.

1. The first one uses uses an empty node before and after the formula that belongs under the wide hat.

   - Disadvantage: The added vertical height will not be taken into calculation
   - Advantage: Math style (display, text, script, scriptscript) is not effected (other then in the `\vphantom`.
2. The second one *is* a node.

   - Disadvantage: Math style is lost. (Change the first `\frac` into a `\tfrac` to realize.)
   - Advantage: Vertical height is known to math mode.

Another disadvantage over `\widehat` is, that the line width doesn't change over the course of the path.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

% Solution 1
\newcounter{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{\tikz[baseline, inner sep=0, overlay, remember picture] \node[anchor=base] (#2) {\vphantom{#1}};}

\newcommand{\widehatarrow}[1]{%
    \tikzmark[#1]{widehatarrow\thetikzmark} #1 \tikzmark[#1]{endwidehatarrow\thetikzmark}%
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[-to] (widehatarrow\thetikzmark.north)++(.05em,.4ex) -- ($(widehatarrow\thetikzmark.north)!.5!(endwidehatarrow\thetikzmark.north)+(.05em,.8ex)$) -- ($(endwidehatarrow\thetikzmark.north)+(.05em,.4ex)$);%
    \stepcounter{tikzmark}%
}

% Solution 2
\newcommand{\Widehatarrow}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline] {
    \node[inner sep=0, anchor=base] (widehatarrow){$#1$};
    \draw[-to] (widehatarrow.north west)++(.05em,.4ex) -- ($(widehatarrow.north west)!.5!(widehatarrow.north east)+(.05em,.8ex)$) -- ($(widehatarrow.north east)+(.05em,.4ex)$);%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation} % Solution 1
\widehatarrow{A, B} \cdot \widehatarrow{x, y} = \widehatarrow{A, y, B, x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} % Solution 2
\Widehatarrow{A, B} \cdot \Widehatarrow{x, y} = \Widehatarrow{A, y, B, x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} % Compare both solutions
 \frac{1}{\widehatarrow{A, B} \cdot \Widehatarrow{A, B}} = \frac{1}{\widehatarrow{A, B} \cdot \widehatarrow{A, B}} = \frac{1}{\Widehatarrow{A, B} \cdot \Widehatarrow{A, B}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: MWE compiled]

---

(By egreg) It's possible to overcome the limitations with `\Widehatarrow`, by using a `\vphantom` and `\mathpalette`:

```
\newcommand{\Widehatarrow}[1]{\mathpalette\Widehatarrowaux{#1}}
\newcommand{\Widehatarrowaux}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#1\widehat{#2}}
  \tikz[baseline] {
    \node[inner sep=0, anchor=base] (widehatarrow){$#1#2$};
    \draw[-to] (widehatarrow.north west)++(.05em,.4ex)
     -- ($(widehatarrow.north west)!.5!(widehatarrow.north east)+(.05em,.8ex)$)
     -- ($(widehatarrow.north east)+(.05em,.4ex)$);%
  }%
}
```

Now the height of `\Widehatarrow{AB}` will be the same as the height of `\widehat{AB}` and the sizes will be respected, as shown by trying

```
$\Widehatarrow{AB}=A_{\Widehatarrow{XY}}$
```

Comment: Anyone, who has an idea how to solve the problems (“disadvantage”), is welcome to comment or point me in the right direction. `:)`

Comment: Both problems can be solved with some *cognoscenti* trickery, for `\Widehatarrow`. I'll add it to your solution.

Comment: The first solution is quite buggy with me (see http://www.mirari.fr/BJr2 ) (and it compiles differently every time). Anyway, the second (and its modified version) works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul22 Yes, the first one needs two compilations and is superseded by the second one (especially with egreg's addition), anyway.